# How to get latest Service Stack v3 build?

Tags: git, servicestack, nuget, ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-bsd

Last v3 build published on [nuget.org is 3.9.71](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/3.9.71) - since then there have been lots of fixes that I would like to include in my project.

So what is preferred way to do that? Obviously I can add v3 branch from Github as Submodule in my Git, then reference all needed `.csproj` in my `.sln` - but I would prefer just having DDLs (through NuGet ideally).

Is anyone currently doing nightly builds that I can reference though NuGet / Git with just DLLs? Or should I start doing that?

Comment: Is there a specific v3 fix you are waiting on? v3 is pretty stable.

Comment: @Scott See my latest comment on your answer. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will not be nightly builds. ServiceStack v3 (BSD) will be released on a **monthly basis to NuGet**, as noted [here](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3). So compiling your own version from GitHub in the interim period between NuGet releases will have to do.

> Service Stack still hosts continuous integration builds and publishes monthly periodic releases of ServiceStack v3 to NuGet.

I am not sure where you are seeing lots of fixes. I note [a commit a month ago](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b2b401b8f53a4f53adab7a09a5c9ca28f15165ee) on the [v3 branch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commits/v3), and a minor changes on the [v3-fixes branch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commits/v3-fixes). So 3.9.71 is still pretty fresh.

I wouldn't expect as many commits to v3 for it to be necessary to do nightly builds, as a lot of effort is being concentrated into v4.

Comment: Well, the problem is - I can't seem to reference stuff that's supposed to be in 3.9.71 - as if those Nuget DLLs are over 4 months old. For example I don't have [StringLength] attribute. Also, I've went through files in git/build/ and they are stuck to 3.9.60 and not working. If they switched to continuations integration I would understand that - but then I would love if scripts for continuations integration would be in Git. So, there is nothing like I ask? I would need to fix files in build\ and then publish pull request?

Comment: Here is the question that illustrate a simple thing I'm missing (that was supposedly added to ServiceStack 4 months ago but is not in 3.9.71 dlls): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462671/servicestack-ormlite-equivalent-of-single-singleordefault-from-entity-framework

Comment: @kape123 It won't ever be added to ServiceStack v3. v3 is BSD, v4 is Commercial. The changes there were for v4. If you want that functionality you need to get v4. ServiceStack aren't going to add to v3 and v4. Then no one would buy v4.

Comment: @kape123 You can implement similar functionality yourself, and submit it to the v3 project. But you won't be able to use the code of v4, that already provides the functionality you are after, as it's licensed commercially.

Comment: It's weird that StringLength is not part of the v3 package since even on [old Google Code repository](http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/OrmLite) it is shown in example - was it removed since? And what is my option if I want to stick with v3? Just make peace with crazy varchar(8000) fields in database? That's my only option? And also since Require is also not available what to do if I want non-nullable nvarchar fields in database?

Comment: @kape123 `StringLength` is not a ServiceStack attribute. It's an attribute implemented by Microsoft's DataAnnotations. [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: OK, that makes sense - from v3 to v4 there was switch to ServiceStack attributes. Man, there are so many subtle settings in ServiceStack. Thanks for the help.